# Counting with more than one condition for same column

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I want to count the number of sids who takes 2 specific courses(crn)
I can display the said sids but for some reason i cannot count them.

I want to display the number of students who takes crn = 12345 and crn = 20976

here is my table

```
  sid  |  crn  | grade
 12321 | 12345 |   A
 12321 | 20976 |   B
 21008 | 12345 |   C
 21008 | 20976 |   A
 21008 | 28469 |   D
 21090 | 12345 |   C
 21090 | 20976 |   F
```

here is the code that works

```
 select sid from takes where crn in (12345 , 20976 ) group by sid HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

here is the codes that i've tried

```
 select count(sid) from takes where crn in (12345 , 20976 ) group by sid HAVING COUNT(*) = 2

 select sid, count(sid) from takes where crn in ( '12345', '20976') GROUP By sid HAVING count(*) > 1

 select count(sid) from takes where (select sid from takes where crn in ( '12345', '20976') GROUP By sid HAVING count(*) > 1 )

 select sid, count(sid) from takes where (select sid from takes where crn in ( '12345', '20976') HAVING count(*) > 1 ) GROUP BY sid
```

So here is my question, how can i make this thing work? I mean how hard can it be for some code to count things that it can display and display that number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select sid
      from takes
      where crn in (12345 , 20976 )
      group by sid 
      having count(*) = 2
     ) s;
```

Comment: dude, thank you so so so much. I've been trying different things, some complicated stuff with sums and more than 2 counts and it was as easy as this? You are awesome!

Altho, where is that 's' coming from at the end?

Comment: @O'Kara . . . `s` is a table alias.  Very useful in SQL.